# Python - Netlify Page not found error 404 even when the site is built without any error

Tags: python, flask, netlify

I have made a flask web application and wanted to host it with netlify. When I try to preview/open my site , page not found error rises.

My site is deployed successfully! I read through other documentations but still the problem was not resolved. I have my `index.html` also included in my application

Link to my Github repository = https://github.com/PranaySadani/PredictX

Please tell me what I should do to resolve the issue at hand!

Comment: Does your website work on localhost?

Comment: Yes it works perfectly fine there

Comment: What is the error specifically? Does it happen to all the pages or only a few?

Comment: I have deployed my application on netlify and my build / deployement is successful but when I open the link page not found error shows up. Link to the application - https://predictx.netlify.app

Comment: Is your website static?

Comment: Your website is not likely to be static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netlify can only serve static web pages, which is not the case when you are using flask (with sign in and sign up functionality with database), you might want to check out other services like Heroku.